# Java Download Large File Stops Unexpectedly

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, stream

I am downloading a large file (500MB to 1GB) from a java spring tomcat application.

The method below to download the file has been working great in the past, but today it started behaving weirdly. Only about the first 20MB - 50MB would get downloaded before the browser (chrome) thought the file was finished.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/DownloadPDFSaved/{group}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downloadGroup(@PathVariable String group, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if(!StringUtils.hasText(group)) {
        response.sendError(400, "Group is empty");
        return;
    }
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(getPDFZipFilePathForGroup(group)));
    IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

In the tomcat logs, I can see a `ClientAbortException`, but it doesn't give too much useful information.

Do I need to set the content length? If so, would I set the content length to the size of the file? Can you see anything else that would be causing an issue downloading a large zip file?

Stacktrace

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:389) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:339) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:414) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:402) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:97) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:457) ~[SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:135) ~[IOUtils.class:3.11]
at web.controllers.TrialController.downloadGroup(TrialController.java:281) [TrialController.class:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_11]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_11]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_11]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_11]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [InvocableHandlerMethod.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [InvocableHandlerMethod.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) [RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705) [RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [DispatcherServlet.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [DispatcherServlet.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [FrameworkServlet.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) [FrameworkServlet.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618) [servlet-api.jar:?]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [FrameworkServlet.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [servlet-api.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [FilterSecurityInterceptor.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [FilterSecurityInterceptor.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [ExceptionTranslationFilter.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [SessionManagementFilter.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [RequestCacheAwareFilter.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [BasicAuthenticationFilter.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [LogoutFilter.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [FilterChainProxy.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [FilterChainProxy.class:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [DelegatingFilterProxy.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [DelegatingFilterProxy.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at web.spring_config.CaseInsensitiveRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(CaseInsensitiveRequestFilter.java:23) [CaseInsensitiveRequestFilter.class:?]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:66) [Log4jServletFilter.class:2.0-beta9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_11]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.9]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_11]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:134) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:173) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:139) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:197) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:41) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:320) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:118) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:257) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:492) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:384) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.9]
... 86 more
```

Comment: Have you tried with browsers other than Chrome?

Comment: Yes same issue with IE and FireFox. Just seems to be this one file...

Comment: Post the stack trace in your question. Always.

Comment: Very strange. I've never heard of a socket timeout exception in a write in Java. Also curious that it comes from Coyote code and not the JDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the `content-length` header seems to fix the problem. I am guessing that the browser was cutting the download short without the header and that was causing the `ClientAbortException`.

Here is the updated and working code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/DownloadPDFSaved/{group}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downloadGroup(@PathVariable String group, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if(!StringUtils.hasText(group)) {
         response.sendError(400, "Group is empty");
        return;
    }

    File zipFile = new File(getPDFZipFilePathForGroup(group));
    //set content-length header
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", Long.toString(zipFile.length()));         
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
    IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```